# Matlab: Euclidean norm (or difference) between two vectors

Tags: matlab

I'd like to calculate the Euclidean distance between a vector G and each row of an array C, while dividing each row by a value in a vector GSD. What I've done seems **very** inefficient. What's my biggest overhead?
Could I speed it up?

```
m=1E7;
G=1E5*rand(1,8);
C=1E5*[zeros(m,1),rand(m,8)]; 
GSD=10*rand(1,8);

%I've taken the log10 of the values because G and C are very large in magnitude. 
%Don't know if it's worth it.

for i=1:m
    dG(i,1)=norm((log10(G)-log10(C(i,2:end)))/log10(GSD));
end
```

Using the examples from below, they don't all give the same answer. In fact none of them give the same answer (see following figure using:

```
dG = pdist2(log10(G),log10(C(:,2:end)),'mahalanobis',diag(log10(GSD))); %(1)

dG = sqrt(sum((log10(G)-log10(C(:,2:end))./log10(GSD)).^2,2)); 

tmp=bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,log10(G),log10(C(:,2:end))),log10(GSD)); %(4)
dG = sqrt(sum(tmp.^2,2));
```

[image]

Comment: Which one of the three gives the same answer as your own code? I would guess that the Mahalanobis one is wrong, but I don’t immediately see what is different about the other two.

Comment: Also, you do change the math when taking the logarithm of your data. I don’t see why you do this, and why you think you’re computing the Euclidean distance. I would not use `log10` in your code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo G is some experimental data and GSD the standard deviation for each point in G. C are prediction of G from a mathematical model by trying different parameter values. I want to find a parameter value that makes a row in C that minimise the difference between C and G, which takes into account the effect of the standard deviations. So I thought I should take logs in case there are differences in orders magnitude. What do you think?

Comment: Well, note that `log(std(x))~=std(log(x))`, so I don’t think your normalization is correct any more. If you want to compute the Euclidean distance of the logarithm of your data, that’s fine, but take the logarithm first, then normalize, or normalize first, then take the logarithm. You are doing neither. And typically, the normalization (whitening) should take care of orders of magnitude difference. Also note that `log(G)-log(C) = log(G./C)`, think about what that means for your data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pdist2(x,y)`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) to calculate the pairwise distance between all elements in `x` and `y`, thus your example would be something like

```
dG = pdist2(log10(G),log10(C(:,2:end)),'mahalanobis',diag(log10(GSD)).^2);
```

where the name-pair `'mahalanobis',diag(log10(GSD)).^2` puts `log10(GSD)` as weights on the Eucledean, which is the known as the Mahalanobis distance.

Note that the Mahalanobis distance is originally intented for normalising data, thus it is the "covariance" which have to be put as the fourth input, which MATLAB then finds the Cholesky decomposition of (element-wise squareroot when diagonal, as here).

**Implicit expansion**

In newer MATLAB editions, one can also just just the implcit expansion as the first entry is only 1 vector.

```
dG = sqrt(sum(((log10(G)-log10(C(:,2:9)))./log10(GSD)).^2,2));
```

which is probably a tad faster, I do, however, prefer the `pdist2` solution as I find it clearer.

Comment: Thanks Nicky, here my vector has 1 element less than my array's rows. Would it be faster to create a new dummy variable Cdum=C(:,2:9);?

Comment: No that does not matter. You will have to index into it anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand. What do you mean 'you will have to index into it anyway'?

Comment: That is not the problem, `C(:,2:9)` should work, the variable `C` is `10` long in your example so `C(:,2:9)~=C(:,2:end)`. The problem is that I misinterpreted the use of `GSD`. Give me a second to fix it.

Comment: I made a mistake, size(C)=[m,9].

Comment: Nicky, I'm finding that these examples of code don't give me the same distance as each other (see pic above). What do you think's going on?

Comment: @HCAI, I see, please see the updated answer. The fourth input to `pdist2` have to be squared as Matlab automatically finds the Cholesky decomposition (or squareroot in case of diagonal matrices).

Answer (score 1):

The floating point should handle the large magnitude of the input data, up to a certain point with `float` data and with any reasonable value with `double` data

```
realmax('single')
ans =
  3.4028e+38

realmax('double')
ans =
  1.7977e+308
```

With 1e7 values in the +/- 1e5 range, you may expect the square of the Euclidian distance to be in the +/- 1e17 range (5+5+7), which both formats will handle with ease.

In any case, you should vectorize the code to remove the loop (which Matlab has a history of handling very inefficiently, especially in older versions)

With new versions (2016b and later), simply use:

```
tmp=(log10(G)-log10(C(:,2:end)))./log10(GSD);
dG = sqrt(sum(tmp.^2,2)); %row-by-row norm
```

Note that you have to use `./` which is a element-wise division, not `/` which is matrix right division.

The following code will work everywhere

```
tmp=bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,log10(G),log10(C(:,2:end))),log10(GSD));
dG = sqrt(sum(tmp.^2,2)); %row-by-row norm
```

I however believe that the use of log10 is a mathematical error. The result dG will *not* be the Euclidian norm. You should stick with the root mean square of the weighted difference:

```
dG = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,G,C(:,2:end)),GSD).^2,2)); % all versions
dG = sqrt(sum((G-C(:,2:end)./GSD).^2,2)); %R2016b and later
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brice for these answers. Why do you say that the log10 is a mathematical error? I don't absolutely have to use the Euclidean distance, but it does need to be something that takes into consideration the values GSD. GSD actually at standard deviations of  each point in G. Each row of C are predictions of G.

Comment: I'm just looking at these again. They don't give the same distance (see pic above). Any thoughts about what's going on?